# Find number of all spanning tree of $G_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> Find $d_n$ which is number of all spanning tree of $G_n$ where $V =
>  \left\{ 0,1,...,n  \right\} $ and $$E = \left\{ \left\{ 0,i \right\} :
>  i \in [n]  \right\} \cup   \left\{ \left\{ i,i+1 \right\} : i \in
>  [n-1]  \right\}  $$

This is our graph
[image: graph]
And I found that 
$$ d_n = 2d_{n-1} \text{ for } n \ge 4$$
$d_1 = 1$
$d_2 = 1$
$d_3 = 3$ 
But the pattern looks too simple, can somebody verify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you messed up the indices. $d_0=1, d_1=1, d_2=3$. 
Looking for a recursion is a good idea (probably the right approach). But again, you made a small mistake.

Case 1: the edge $(0,n+1)$ is in the tree but $(n,n+1)$ is not. Then there are $d_n$ solutions.

Case 2: the edge $(0,n+1)$ is not in the tree but $(n,n+1)$ is there. Then there are $d_n$ solutions.

Cse 3: both edges containing $(n+1)$ is in the tree. I claim that there are $d_0+d_1+\cdots +d_{n-1}$ solutions in this case. (Think about it.)

So the recursive rule is $d_{n+1}=d_0+\cdots +d_{n-1}+2d_n$. (This also works for $n=2$.)

Seems to me that this gives $d_n= F_{2n}$ for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: You are right that I have missed case 3 but are you sure that in third case it will be $d_0+d_1+\cdots +d_{n-1}$, not just $d_n$? Previous form of graph is still obtained in $d_n$ ways.

Comment: Think about it! Make a sub case distinction in terms of where the path on the first level ends that starts with the edge $(n+1,n)$.

Comment: by $(n+1,n)$ you mean $(0,n)$, yes?

Comment: Please, draw a picture, and think about my answer before asking for further details. I meant what I wrote. (If after 10-15 minutes thinking you still don't understand, then it is OK to ask for clarification. But you are asking more immediately, without investing any effort.) I have corrected your mistake and provided all the main ideas you need for the solution. It is your turn to work now.

Comment: you have right A.Pongracz, give me some time.

Comment: I have drawn some cases and currently I understand that the third case is other than first and second because edges can be transformed (or just removed in some cases because we have already touch them): http://i.imgur.com/OdqFasP.png But I still not sure why we add $d_0$ $d_1$ etc because as I marked for example on red color: red edge (and blue from new vertex) contains: 1;0;3;4 but no 2.

Comment: $n+1$ is connected to $0$ and to $n$. Think about the edge $(n+1,n)$ as the first edge in a path. This path can end in $n$ vertices: $n$, $n-1$, ..., $1$. If it ends in $k$, then $0$ is not connected to $k, k+1, \ldots, n-1$, so that part of the tree is known. The only question left is how to connect the vertices $0,1,\ldots, k-1$. This can be done in $d_{k-1}$ ways by the definition of the sequence $d_n$. So depending on $k$, which can be $1, \ldots, n$, we have $d_0, \ldots, d_{n-1}$ possibilities, respectively.

Comment: I know where I failed! It is obvious that spanning tree doesn't contain cycles but in my thinking I didn't take into account that (because if we connect any vertex from out path to $0$ we get a cycle!!!!!!!) Thanks professor for great tips!

Comment: Can I ask you additional question - do you recommend some book, set of task to discreet mathematics with level of task similar to this?